# Intuition for Plethystic Exponentiation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, superconformality

I have been studying [Abjit Gadde's lecture notes on the superconformal index](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.13630), and I can't seem to understand what the intuition for the plethystic exponentiation is. He motivates it with the supersymmetric harmonic oscillator
$$L=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2-\frac{1}{2}x^2+i\overline{\psi}\dot{\psi}-\overline{\psi}\psi.$$
Long story short there are bosonic and fermionic creation/annihilation operators
$$a_B^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-ip+x),\ \ \ a_B=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(ip+x)$$
$$a_F^\dagger=\overline{\psi},\ \ \ a_F=\psi$$
$$[a_b,a_B^\dagger]=1,\ \ \ \{a_F,a_F^\dagger\}=1$$
such that the Hamiltonian can be rewritten
$$H=a_B^\dagger a_B+a_F^\dagger a_F.$$
This is a free theory, so it's not hard to compute the partition function
$$Z=\mathrm{Tr}\, e^{-\beta H}=(1+e^{-\beta}+e^{-2\beta}+...)+(e^{-\beta}+e^{-2\beta}+...)=\frac{1+e^{-\beta}}{1-e^{-\beta}}.$$
The argument is that you should take the "single-letter" partition function (over the states with
only a single particle), and then make replacements
$$z_B=e^{-\beta}\to\frac{1}{1-e^{-\beta}}$$
$$z_F=e^{-\beta}\to1+e^{-\beta}$$
I'm good with this line of argument. However, what I don't understand is how one gets from here to the argument that we use plethysic exponentiation:
$$\mathrm{PE}[f(x)]=\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}f(x^n)\right),\ \ \widetilde{\mathrm{PE}}[f(x)]=\exp\left(-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}(-1)^nf(x^n)\right)$$
$$Z=\mathrm{PE}[z_B(e^{-\beta})]\widetilde{\mathrm{PE}}[z_F(e^{-\beta})]$$
I get that this gives the right answer in this particular case (plugging in $z_{B/F}=e^{-\beta}$ gives an exponential of the Taylor series of $\mp\log(1\mp e^{-\beta})$), but why is this something useful to define? Why didn't we just go for the naive $T[f(x)]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(x)^n$, $\widetilde{T}[f(x)]=1+f(x)$? I'm just a bit puzzled as to the intuition of defining these plethystic exponentials.